# Is DBT right choice for SQL pipeline?

Tags: sql, dbt

I am looking to move our SQL pipeline built on R which executes a bunch of SQL scripts in a particular order to DBT. I am not sure if DBT is the right choice to move for this scenario.

**Scenario**:-
Pipeline looks like-

SQL script 1 -> script 2 -> script 3 -> script 4 -> script 5 etc

**script 1** - Creates Table A from an existing table

`CREATE table A  AS  Select * from existing_table1;`

**script 2** - Creates Table B

`CREATE table B AS Select * from existing_table2;`

**script 3** - Adds new column in Table A and add values via UPDATE statement using Table B

`ALTER TABLE A ADD column p INT; UPDATE A SET  p = A.col1+B.col1 FROM B;`

**script 4** - Creates Table C

`CREATE table B AS Select * from existing_table3;`

**script 5** - Adds new column in Table A and add values via UPDATE statement using Table C

`ALTER TABLE A ADD column q INT; UPDATE A SET  q = A.col2+C.col2 FROM C;`

Now in the existing pipeline, since each script is isolated SQL statements so they are simple to execute.

But in DBT, as per documentation, there can be one model file for each table and it has to single SELECT statement.

**Some confusions/questions I have**:-

1. How can I accommodate script1, script 3 and script 5 in single SELECT statement considering there can be only one model file for Table A
2. If I am able to do the above point, How will I maintain the order of execution in DBT for script 2, which  needs to be executed before the UPDATE happening in Script 3

Comment: you can write a macro for exmple

Answer (score 0):

The dbt documentation describing one model per table allows you to define several input tables, so to speak.

Specifically, common table expressions (CTE, see also [this page](https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/why-the-fishtown-sql-style-guide-uses-so-many-ctes/1091)) may help you define one table in a select statement while taking three upstream tables as input or dependencies. Depending on table size and joining or transformation logic you might consider bringing fewer or more steps of your pipeline into one or several models.

Bringing your five steps example into one model might look like this:

```
with existing_table1 as (
select * from source_existing_table1
),
existing_table2 as (
select * from source_existing_table2
),
existing_table3 as (
select * from source_existing_table3
),
final as (
select
    existing_table1.*,
    existing_table1.col1 + existing_table2.col1 as p,
    existing_table1.col2 + existing_table3.col2 as q
from existing_table1
inner join existing_table2
    on existing_table1.id = existing_table2.id --replace with your join condition
inner join existing_table3
    on existing_table1.id = existing_table3.id --replace with your join condition
)
select * from final
```